# If a class extends another class, can the extended class be initialized rather than extending it?

Tags: java

If a class extends another class, can the extended class be initialized rather than extending it?

Example 1:

```
public class FoodListAdapter extends BaseAdapter{
    //rest of the codes in here
}
```

Example 2:

```
public class FoodListAdapter {
    private BaseAdapter fAdapter;
    //rest of the codes here
}
```

Can Example2 give a similar result as that of Example1?

Comment: One is called an [**is-a**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Is-a) relationship. The other is called a [**has-a**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Has-a) relationship.

Answer (score 1):

Example 1 is Inheritance.

Example 2 is Aggregation, a directional one way association representing a Has-A relationship.

Example 1 is more brittle as it directly exposes users to the underlying `BaseAdapter` class. Example 2 can encapsulate and delegate calls to `BaseAdapter`. If one day you decide to remove `BaseAdapter`, users of the `FoodListAdapter` class never have to know.

Comment: Please if example2 is possible how will it be coded using BaseAdapter ?

Comment: How you have done already, just pass in a BaseAdapter by constructor or setter method.

Answer (score 1):

Both strategies are good. It depends on what you are trying to achieve.

The first example is inheritance, while the second is delegation.

Both are well known design patterns.

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delegation_pattern